# Understanding Push Down Automata

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I do not understand the arrows in the PDA graph...

I have a PDA that accepts all strings with parentheses nested like `((((()))))`, `(())`, `((()))` etc. It has two states where the first state has an arrow that loops and the behavor of this is described as `(,ε/(`.

For what I could see, this description would accept the `(` sign if there is an ε on the top of the stack, and if there is, the `ε` would be replaced with `(`.

So if the stack looked like this in the beginning:
`ε`

it looks like this now:
`(ε`

How can it be so that this loop arrow keep accepting every `(` sign even if the `ε` is not at the top of the stack anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a another behavior for that state that said:   (, (->(
This transition should take you to another state(an auxillary state).
That aux state's only transition would be ε, ε->(

From your original state you would need to pop ( off the stack when you see a )
), (->ε

Here is a similiar example of mine that contains more a's than b's (problem number 1)[image]